# Regex Regular expressions R

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract the string lets say "1 year of experience" or "1-2 year of experience". My input is varying, therefore, this means that my regex will work accurately on the string but will also give me garbage value.

```
\\d.*experience
```

The above mentioned regular expression does the required. However, if I want to add words multiple in this expression that when that word is present then it does not matches. This will make sure that I extract only the desired and gets an NA if my string has one or more particular words mentioned.

Examples:

Currently I am getting both:

**need to disregard the string on the basis of let's say am or pm or any other word**
"7:00 am .to 3:30 pm mon-fri. ideal candidate will be computer literate, have experience operating and hi-lo, be able to read a micrometer and has previous experience in the steel industry loading/unloading steel coils from trucks and moving them safely into the production area.must be detail oriented as the person may be responsible for receiving material and entering data into the computer inventory system.overtime may be required periodically.pay will be based on experience and benefits including paid time off are available after successful completion of introductory period.*interviewed candidates will be tested on crane safety*job type: full-timepay: $15.00 - $17.00 per hourbenefits:401(k)401(k) matchingdental insurancedisability insuranceflexible spending accounthealth insurancelife insurancepaid time offvision insuranceschedule:day shiftmonday to fridayexperience"

**Need to keep as it is**
"1 year of experience"

Can someone please help me in embedding the regex in my expression that will disregard the whole string if string contains any of the words found in or statement within regex

Comment: [\d+(?:-\d+)?(?:\s+years? of)\s+experience](https://regex101.com/r/WPcjPz/1)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus's expression in r: `str_extract("1-2 years of experience",\\d+(?:-\\d+)?(?:\\s+years? of)\\s+experience)`

Answer (score 0):

You might try limiting the `.` operand to some maximum limit with `{,}`:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(string = strings, "\\d+.{0,20}experience")
[1] "1 year of experience"   "1-2 year of experience" NA
```

If you wanted to combine this with a negative assertion you could try:

```
str_extract(string = c("7 pm experience", "7 cm years of experience"),
                       "\\d+(?!.*(am|pm).*).{0,20}?experience")
#[1] NA                         "7 cm years of experience"
```

**Sample Data**

```
strings <- c("1 year of experience", "1-2 year of experience", "7:00 am .to 3:30 pm mon-fri. ideal candidate will be computer literate, have experience operating and hi-lo, be able to read a micrometer and has previous experience in the steel industry loading/unloading steel coils from trucks and moving them safely into the production area.must be detail oriented as the person may be responsible for receiving material and entering data into the computer inventory system.overtime may be required periodically.pay will be based on experience and benefits including paid time off are available after successful completion of introductory period.interviewed candidates will be tested on crane safetyjob type: full-timepay: $15.00 - $17.00 per hourbenefits:401(k)401(k) matchingdental insurancedisability insuranceflexible spending accounthealth insurancelife insurancepaid time offvision insuranceschedule:day shiftmonday to fridayexperience"
```

Comment: [`.` catches to much garbage.](https://regex101.com/r/VTeQGD/1) OP seems to have narrowed their possibilities to 1 or 2 expressions.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, agreed. I don't follow [tag:regex] specifically, but in [tag:r], I rarely find the OP to narrows their use case very well.

Comment: That symptom is most certainly not specific to r, hah

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Can you elaborate what do you mean by OP
. does give me garbage values

Comment: @ArsalanR OP = Original Poster. In this situation that is you.

Comment: Thanks @IanCampbell, it has done the trick mostly. Just for the sake of argument I was trying to use look arounds specifically not followed by e.g. "a(?!c)". But were not getting the right result. Is there a way that I can use to add certain words in my regex to disregard the whole string.

I am scraping the whole website. The answer you have provided really helped in pre-processing

Comment: @ArsalanR You can add in a `(!? )` assertion. See my edit.